# auto-deleting element in doubly link list

Tags: c, doubly-linked-list

After certain number of steps, the loaded (particular)element should be get (auto) deleted by itself on execution/run time..I want to pre define it so it can perform auto-deletion in doubly linked list

```
void del_begin()
{
  struct node *temp;

 if(start==NULL)
      return;
    else
    { temp=start;
        start=start->next;
                start->prev=NULL;
        printf("Unloaded Wagon =%s ",temp->num);
        free(temp);
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @MikeCAT sir I am Implementing a project in doubly linked list in c and I want to delete element by itself (auto-deletion) after certain number of steps which we will predefine it

Comment: Now I was told what you want to do. Then, what is your *question*?

Comment: @MikeCAT whenever I insert an element I want to delete that element automatically, after certain numbers of insertion, so that user don't need to delete, it should be perform by itself.

Comment: Do what you want. Post **some questions** if you have any.

Comment: @Nitin you mean that you want each element to have a 'lifetime count' that gets decremented on each insert(), and the element gets removed/deleted when the count reaches zero?

Comment: @MartinJames yes sir..but only for those elements ..which we will predifine to delete automatically

Comment: OK, that's fairly easy. Add an 'int lifetime' to your node struct.  If you insert an element that needs a limited lifetime, set it to the lifetime.  If it's to have infinite lifetime, set it to -1.  On insert() iterate the whole list and, if the lifetime is not -1, decrement it and, if then 0, remove/delete the element.

Comment: I guess your question is how to do this? Add an attribute `int lifetime`. If an element should be auto deleted, then assign a value greater equals 0 to it. After inserting an element, you decrease the lifetime of any element which lifetime is greater than 0 and remove elements with a lifetiem of 0.

Comment: @pytheos This site aint big enough for the both of us.. :)

Comment: Have a pointer to the first element and keep track of how many items are in the double linked list, once it reaches N then delete the first item and move the pointer to the next item. That way you keep constant size.

Comment: @MartinJames Great minds think alike ;-)

Comment: @pytheos Thanks Allot.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code implements a doubly linked list where each element can be assigned a lifetime value. Each call to `insert` will decrease the lifetime by `1`. If a node has a lifetime of `0` it is being removed from the list. Nodes with a negative lifetime value are ignored and hence never removed from the list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dll{
    struct node* head;
};

struct node {
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
    int value;
    int lifetime;

};

void insert(struct dll*, int, int); // insert a new node
void step(struct dll*); // decrease the lifetime by one and remove "dead" nodes
void print(struct dll*); // print the nodes and their lifetime

int main(void) {
    struct dll* dll = malloc(sizeof(struct dll));
    dll->head = NULL;
    insert(dll, 1, -1);
    insert(dll, 2, 5);
    insert(dll, 3, 3);
    insert(dll, 4, 0);
    insert(dll, 5, 1);
    print(dll);
}

void insert(struct dll* dll, int value, int lifetime) {
    print(dll);
    step(dll);
    struct node* n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->value = value;
    n->lifetime = lifetime;
    if(dll->head == NULL) {
        dll->head = n;
        n->prev = dll->head;
        n->next = dll->head;
    } else {
        n->prev = dll->head->prev;
        dll->head->prev->next = n;
        dll->head->prev = n;
        n->next = dll->head;
    }
}

void step(struct dll* dll) {
    if(dll->head != NULL) {
        struct node* n = dll->head;
        do{
            if(n->lifetime == 0) {
                // remove the node
                struct node* next = n->next;
                n->prev->next = n->next;
                n->next->prev = n->prev;
                free(n);
                n = next;
            } else if(n->lifetime > 0){
                // decrease lifetime by one
                n->lifetime = n->lifetime - 1;
                n = n->next;
            } else {
                n = n->next;
            }
        } while(n != dll->head);
    }
}

void print(struct dll* dll) {
    if(dll->head != NULL) {
        struct node* n = dll->head;
        do{
            printf("%d(%d) ", n->value, n->lifetime);
            n = n->next;
        } while(n != dll->head);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

The following is being printed out upon executing the code:

```
1(-1)
1(-1) 2(5)
1(-1) 2(4) 3(3)
1(-1) 2(3) 3(2) 4(0)
1(-1) 2(2) 3(1) 5(1)
```